# Running codes on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I installed code run extension I cant write anything if I run the code with extension. On the other hand if I use shift+enter its going line by line and I dont think it should be like this

I wrote some codes, and I want to run my codes. For example I will write lionel then the surname part will come and I will write messi and the team part. Every line will execute in order. In the pycharm you can do it but I couldn't have found it in VS Code. Can anyone help me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Welcome to SO!

Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

to adjust your question. I want to remove the downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If the extension mentioned in your article is code-runner, you can add the following code to **settings.json**:

"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

or you can check the option in the settings:

[image]

You can also use the "Run python file" which is provided by Python extension.

[image]